# How to sort gsheet table according to a custom sort function?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a gsheet [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZj2cNJb5f67O0aZKsPhFLwheV5fqO2K2Uovv43Tq8o/edit?usp=sharing) with columns: `version, valueA`

I wrote an app-script function that compares two versions.

How can I use this custom cooperator to sort the whole table according to this comperator?

```
function sortAnalyticsVersionsDesc() {
  var versions = activeSpreadsheet.getRangeByName(MY_RANGE).getValues().filter(item => item[0] != "");
  versions.sort(_compareVer);
}
```

I want the `valueA` to be sorted accordingly.

[sortSpecObj](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)    `The columns to sort by` gives no option to provide a custom sorting function.

Do I have to copy the whole table to memory? But even then - how do I sort a matrix?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: `sortSpecObj Object The columns to sort by.` gives no option to provide a custom sorting function.

Comment: @Cooper, thanks but your links don't answer my question

Comment: The second reference includes a discussion of a compare function for sorting arrays.  If you want to sort the two dimensional array you will have to create a compare function for your specific needs.  You may wish to include JavaScript in your tag list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sortAnalyticsVersionsDesc() {
  var lines = activeSpreadsheet.getRangeByName(ANALYTICS_DATA_TABLE).getValues().filter(item => item[0] != "");
  lines = lines.sort(_compareLinesWithVer);
  activeSpreadsheet.getRangeByName(ANALYTICS_DATA_TABLE).setValues(lines)
}

function _compareLinesWithVer(a, b) {
return _compareVer(a[2], b[2]);
}

function _compareVer(a, b) {
```